# Why does there happen the dependency cycle problem? Although I know the Spring Framework has already solved the dependency cycle problem

Tags: java, spring

There happen the dependency cycle problem. Follow is the Spring Framework info:

```xml
The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

   authenticateController (field private com.aust.sgc.authenticate.AuthenticateProcessor com.aust.controller.AuthenticateController.authenticateProcessor)
      ↓
   authenticateProcessor (field private java.util.List com.aust.sgc.authenticate.AuthenticateProcessor.authenticateServices)
      ↓
   enterpriseAuthenticateService
┌─────┐
|  categoryServiceImpl
↑     ↓
|  demandServiceImpl
└─────┘
```

But when I add the @Lazy, the problem is solved. I hardly restore the phenomenon in other place, and I don't know the reason. I would appreciate it if you could explain it to me early.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring a bean as `@Lazy` tells Springboot not to initialize it on startup. But only initialize it when it is needed.

Take the example without `@Lazy` with a restaurant:

You go to the restaurant and at the table the server is already there.

With `@Lazy` the server comes when you ask him.